# looping over ASCII values to XOR input

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to XOR all the ASCII values in a .txt file with all the ASCII values up to 256. My input .txt file contains the ASCII values in hex format. So for instance, my input file has **"49 f3 54 f3 5f f3 47 f4 43 e8 49 e9"** and I want to XOR each value with 0x00 followed by 0x01, 0x02, 0x03 and so on and print the result in a new line for every hex value. I have written the following the code in C++ but it always prints the original content.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {

vector <char> decrypt; 
char ch;
int index;

ifstream infile;
ofstream outfile;

infile.open("prob3.txt");
outfile.open("results3_p1.txt");

if(!infile)
{
    cout << "Error opening input file" << endl;
    return 0;
}   

for (int a = 0; a < 256; a++)
{

    while(infile >> hex >> index)
    {
        ch = index ^ a;
        decrypt.push_back(ch);
    } 

    for (int i=0; i<decrypt.size(); i++)      // Print the results
    { 
        outfile << decrypt[i];
    }
    outfile << endl;

}

return 0;
}
```

I tried to clear the vector using "decrypt.clear()" but that does not print anything after the first iteration. I am not sure which part of my code in incorrect.

The output from my code -

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not changing 'key'. Maybe you need to use 'a' instead?

You'll reach end of file after first a iteration. You may need to reset file pointer. But this isn't efficient. It your case you probably always iterate through same decrypt array (initialized during first iteration)

Better store all the values from file in some array an then iterate through this array.

I'd suggest something like :

```
while(infile >> hex >> index)
{
       decrypt.push_back(index);
} 
for (int a = 0; a < 256; a++)
{  
    for (int i=0; i<decrypt.size(); i++)      // Print the results
    { 
        ch = decrypt[i] ^ a;    
        outfile << ch;
    }
    outfile << endl;
}
```

Comment: Does it work. For me it still looks like not working code. I've added sample. It's copy-paste so maybe have some typos. But in general it should work. you probably need to cast to (char)

Answer (score 0):

Since you'd like to XOR the values with 0...256 your loop variable "a" should actually be "key" or vice versa.